# Django ImportError at /user/login d doesn't look like a module path

Tags: python, django, web, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create a simple login page using th LoginView from django.contrib.auth. Whenever I try to login a user a receive the following error:
ImportError at /user/login
d doesn't look like a module path
[image: Complete Error Message]

This is my code for activating the view in the url:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path("register", views.register_request, name="register"),
    path("login", auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="user/login.html"), name="login"),
    path("logout", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="user/logout.html"), name="logout")
]
```

This is my html file user.login.html:

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_filters %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Log In</legend>
                    {{ form|crispy }}

            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                Need An Account? <a class="ml-2" href="{% url 'register' %}">Sign Up Now</a>
            </small><br>
            <small class="text-muted">
                <a href="/">Forgot password?</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

#Just as a comment, the logout view works perfectly fine, the error jusr occurs when I hit submit in the login.html.

I have tried adding these lines to the settings.py fileÑ

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)

LOGIN_URL = 'user/login'
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` as a string - it should be an *iterable*. So, add a ***comma*** to make it as an iterable

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
                                              ^^^
)
```